# Java Slug Creation to Python

Tags: java, python

## Problem

My goal is to emulate the Java slug creation function (`makeSlug` below) in Python. However, the combination of Java's [Normalizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) together with the regex pattern is giving me a headache.

My solution using the `unidecode` module in Python works for *most* cases fine but not always as highlighted below (e.g. the German letter `ß` is causing problems).

## Code

**Java Code**

```
import java.text.Normalizer;
import java.text.Normalizer.Form;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class Example {
  private static final Pattern NONLATIN = Pattern.compile("[^\\w-]");

  public static String makeSlug(String input)
  {
      String normalized = Normalizer.normalize(input, Form.NFD);
      String noNonlatinNormalized = NONLATIN.matcher(normalized).replaceAll("");
      return noNonlatinNormalized;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String testString = "thiß-täst";   
    String slug = makeSlug(testString);
    String noNormalize = NONLATIN.matcher(testString).replaceAll("");
    System.out.println(String.format("Start string \t'%s'", testString));
    System.out.println(String.format("Slug creation \t'%s'", slug));
    System.out.println(String.format("Without normalize \t'%s'", noNormalize));
  }
}
```

**Java Output**

```
# Start string  'thiß-täst'
# Slug creation     'thi-tast'
# Without normalize     'thi-tst'
```

**Python Code**

```py
import regex
import unidecode


NONLATIN = regex.compile("[^[:ascii:]-]")    # works better (i.e. closer to Java) than [^\w-]

def make_slug(string: str) -> str:
    unidecoded = unidecode.unidecode(string)
    no_nonlatin_unidecoded = NONLATIN.sub("", unidecoded)
    return no_nonlatin_unidecoded


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_string = "thiß-täst"
    slug = make_slug(test_string)
    no_unidecode = NONLATIN.sub("", test_string)
    print("Start string \t'%s'" % test_string)
    print("Slug creation \t'%s'" % slug)
    print("Without unidecode \t'%s'" % no_unidecode)
```

**Python Output**

```
# Start string    'thiß-täst'        # Same start string
# Slug creation   'thiss-tast'       # PROBLEM -> unidecode turns "ß" to "ss"
# Without unidecode       'thi-tst'  # Regex Java-to-Python translation is OK
```

## Notes

What is more, the behaviour of Java's `Normalizer.normalize` is peculiar:

- One can check that `Normalizer.normalize("thiß-täst", Form.NFD)` returns `"thiß-täst"`
- `NONLATIN.matcher(normalized).replaceAll("")` returns `"thi-tast"` (as returned by `makeSlug`)
- `NONLATIN.matcher("thiß-täst").replaceAll("")` returns `thi-tst` (as shown in the Java Output)

This shows that `Normalizer.normalize` *clearly* has an impact even though it seems as if it left the string untouched.

On the other hand, Python's `unidecode.unidecode` turns `"thiß-täst"` to `thiss-tast`. Turning `ä` to `a` is not problematic since the same is done in Java eventually. However, turning `ß` to `ss` causes problems.

**PS** I would prefer to avoid quick fixes of the form `string.replace("ß", "")` - my goal is adhere to Java as much as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module `unicodedata` might be of interest here:

```py
import regex
import unicodedata


NONLATIN = regex.compile("[^[:ascii:]-]")

def make_slug(string: str) -> str:
    normalized = unicodedata.normalize("NFD", string)
    slug = NONLATIN.sub("", normalized)
    return slug


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_string = "thiß-täst"
    slug = make_slug(test_string)
    print("Start string \t'%s'" % test_string, "Slug creation \t'%s'" % slug, sep="\n")

# Start string    'thiß-täst'
# Slug creation   'thi-tast
```

I think it is fair to assume that Python's `unicodedata.normalize("NFD", string)` is fairly analogous to Java's `Normalizer.normalize(string, Form.NFD)` (or at least comes closer than `unidecode.unidecode(string)`).